# Invalid function mod within lisp to recursively add sum positive integers that are multiples of certain numbers

Tags: recursion, lisp, division, modulo

I am trying to write function that sums all positive integers less than or 
equal to 200 and are multiples of 6 and 7.

What I have is the following:

```
(defun sumFunction(current sum)
    (if (/= current 200)
        (if ((eq (mod current 6) 0) or (eq (mod current 7) 0))
            (setf sum (+ sum current))
            (sumFunction (+ current 1) sum)
        )
        (sumFunction ((+ current 1) sum)
    )
)
```

It is giving me the following error:

Error handler called recursively (:INVALID-FUNCTION NIL IF ""
                                     "~S is invalid as a function."
                                     (EQ (MOD CURRENT 3) 0))

I am unsure of why there is any errors.

If I follow the logic it should return the result I need.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two syntax errors in your code, and there are also some other issues which do not match Lisp style. Please refer to the corrected code below.

```
(defun sumFunction(current sum)
  (if (/= current 200)
      (if (or (eq (mod current 6) 0) (eq (mod current 7) 0))
          (sumFunction (+ current 1) (+ current sum))
        (sumFunction (+ current 1) sum))
    sum))
```

Here is the result.

```
(sumFunction 20 0)
;=> 5731
```

Comment: Thank you, I see now the problems that I had. This helped tremendously!

Comment: Nit pickers corner: use `eql` instead of `eq` to compare numeric values. Or, in this case, use `zerop` as in `(zerop (mod current 6))` instead of `(eq (mod current 6) 0)`.